# UploadFile Telegram bot API

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, fileupload

Как я могу загрузить файл через WebClient.UploadFile на сервера Telegram? И потом отправить его пользователю?

Comment: Уважаемый, ну вы серьёзно? На ruSO куча примеров отправки запросов. Лезем в документацию и смотрим [по какому адресу](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#making-requests) отправлять запрос, далее смотрим [метод](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#senddocument), который отправит нам файл, видим, что он принимает [InputFile](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#inputfile). В итоге видим адрес, нужный метод и тело запроса должно быть в формате `multipart/form-data`. Ну и далее [поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20multipart%2fform-data). Я так понимаю, что это все трудно сделать?

Comment: Я создал вопрос, чтобы самому ответить на него

Comment: Ну тогда вы вопрос грамотно составляйте, вот я зашёл и вижу `загрузить файл через WebClient.UploadFile`. Сразу в голове "ага, человеку не нужны сторонние плагины", а тут на тебе, ответ в виде использования плагина, а не `WebClient.UploadFile` из вопроса...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устанавливаем библиотеку через NuGet (Install-Package Telegram.Bot).
Где File.Open - указываем путь к файлу.
Где iof.FileName - название файла, которое будет отправлено, обязательно с расширением. 
Где "Сообщение" - текст, с которым будет отправлен файл (например: Вот Ваш файл).

```
using (var stream = File.Open(Тут), FileMode.Open))
{
    InputOnlineFile iof = new InputOnlineFile(stream);
    iof.FileName = "";
    var send = await client.SendDocumentAsync(message.Chat.Id, iof, "Сообщение");
}
```